# how to calculate the max by column in a list of lists, with F#

Tags: f#

With the following data (random strings):

```
let data =
    [
        ["shi"; "cjwocij"; "cjwijo"]
        ["abs"; "djw"; "djwjdwojdow"]
        ["djido"; "dkwpkw"; "dpfkpeoep"]
    ]
```

I would like to calculate the max length by column.
I can transform the data into a list of lists of lengths:

```
data |> List.map (fun r -> r |> List.map (fun x -> x.Length))
```

```
index   value
0       [ 3; 7; 6 ]
1       [ 3; 3; 11 ]
2       [ 5; 6; 9 ]
```

but ultimately I'd like to reduce it to:

```
[5; 7; 11]
```

by taking the max of each column

I thought I could do a fold and take the first row as a starting point, but it looks like it'll be quite convoluted.

For context: it's for a function that will take a grid and display it with proper spacing / formatting; all rows must have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need List.transpose. This turns rows into columns and vice versa.

```
data 
|> List.map (fun r -> r |> List.map (fun x -> x.Length)) 
|> List.transpose
|> List.map List.max

val data : string list list =
  [["shi"; "cjwocij"; "cjwijo"]; ["abs"; "djw"; "djwjdwojdow"];
   ["djido"; "dkwpkw"; "dpfkpeoep"]]
val it : int list = [5; 7; 11]
```

Here is a quick explicit version of transpose that might help (or hinder?) you grokking this:

```
let transpose lists =
    [0 .. (List.length (List.head lists)) - 1]
    |> List.map (fun col -> List.map (fun row -> List.item col row) lists )
```

This is the recursive version for completeness but I think the above is clearer if you are new to F#.

```
let rec transpose = function
    | (_::_)::_ as l -> List.map List.head l :: transpose (List.map List.tail l)
    | _ -> []
```

**Update:** I answered this in a comment but for others wondering over the second recursive solution:

The `(_::_)` ensures that a list is not empty. This is the same as `(h::t)` but we don't need to use `h` and `t` and so put the don't care place holder `_` instead.

The second `::` makes sure that the list of lists (listoflists) is non-empty or that `(h::t)::c` = (head of listoflists)::tail of listoflists so `h::t` is the first row, and `c` is all the other rows.

```
(_::_)::_ <=> (headRow0::tailRow0)::tailRows
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks! I understand the first version without difficulty, but I'm struggling a bit with the second one: if I understand, it tries to match the input with the patterns, but I don't get the (_::_)::_ pattern, could you explain it?

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I've instrumented the recursive version with a bunch of printfs to see it work step by step.